# GData: How to avoid hardcoding login info

Tags: python, authentication, google-drive-api, gdata

I am working on a reporting system which automatically updates results overnight and puts them in files on a google drive.
The way it is working right now is by hardcoding the login and password information which is by no means ideal even if it works. A search in StackOverflow does not point this question specifically, which surprises me.
A very simplified example with the relevant sections of code looks like:

```
import gdata.docs.service

class GDrive(object):
    def __init__(self, email, password)
        self.gd_client = gdata.docs.service.DocService()
        self.gd_client.ClientLogin(email, password)
    def upload(self):
        # Code to Upload file somewhere in GDrive.

gd = GDrive("the@email.address", "ThePassword")
gd.upload()
```

Can something be done to avoid writing explicitly the username and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make use of the OAuth2 protocol. It is a secure way to store credentials for a long time (but not forever).

A bit of a short answer from my cell, but check:

https://developers.google.com/drive/about-auth

And this bit makes working with Oauth2 a lot easier:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/platforms/google_app_engine#Decorators

Comment: Great, let me know if it worked out and please mark as answered then.

Answer (score 1):

```
import gdata.docs.service
import sys

class GDrive(object):
    def __init__(self, email, password)
        self.gd_client = gdata.docs.service.DocService()
        self.gd_client.ClientLogin(email, password)
    def upload(self):
        # Code to Upload file somewhere in GDrive.


if __name__ == "__main__":
    username = sys.argv[1]
    password = sys.argv[2]

    gd = GDrive(username, password)
    gd.upload()
```

now run from your commandline like `script.py the@email.address ThePassword` where `script.py` is the name of your python scripts...

Comment: This is OK when running the script manually, but my intention is to make it automated, so that I won't have to wake up at 3am and run the script and feed the login info, so my question maybe how to encrypt the password so that I won't have to hardcode it anywhere.